# PHP : Improve loading time of Object-oriented classes

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

*Note: this question is a bit long*

I have a PHP-based system with `Service-Dao-Model` structure as follow:

```
Service Factory > Foo Service > Core Service > Abstract Service > Service Interface
Dao Factory > Foo Dao > Core Dao > Abstract Dao > Dao
Foo > Core Model > Abstract Model
```

Let me explain bit-by-bit. I try to centralize the codes first by define abstract functions in *Abstract & Interface classes*, then implement default behavior in *Core Service, Core Dao and Core Model*.

Then, the custom functions are written in **Foo Service, Foo Dao and Foo Model**. Last, **Service Factory & Dao Factory** is responsible to create object in [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Other Information: all classes have `log4php` object attached in `__construct()`.

In current development status, I loaded around 65 PHP classes in initialization phase. By adding timer (timed by `microtime(true)`), I found that PHP takes most time (0.02119s) on loading up the classes, next is converting DB result set to object values (0.00608s), last is DB query time (0.00223s). Can't believe that class loading time is 10 times more than DB query time!

**QUESTION**: how to improve PHP initialization time on loading up classes?

Versions : PHP 5.2.16 , Connect to MySQL 5.1 localhost server via MySQLi PHP extension

**UPDATE** eAccelerator is pre-installed in shared hosting! `Zend Engine v2.2.0 with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1`

*p.s. codes can be shared if needed.*

Comment: You might want to consider doing more comprehenisve profiling using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or [xhprof](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof).  There are plenty of things that you could probably improve *first*.  Also, if you haven't already, bytecode caching (via APC and friends) is going to dramatically speed up your initialization phase.

Comment: Do you have eAccelerator or any other caching mechanism in place?

Comment: @BenD No other caching mechanism in use. Will try to look into eAccelerator.

Comment: @Charles will try xdebug / xhprof to create a more profiling details.

Comment: @BenD, I was about to sarcastically ask if eAccelerator was still a thing, thinking it was abandoned long ago.  It's good to know that it's [still alive and kicking](http://eaccelerator.net/).

Comment: Oops. I can't use eAccelerator as I'm currently using shared hosting. No permission to install new packages. Sigh.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, that's going to impact your ability to do real profiling as well.  If you care about performance, you're going to want to control your server.  VPSes are a dime a dozen nowadays, and PHP 5.4 has some great performance and memory improvements...

Comment: Short version: upgrade to 5.4, because there have been huge optimizations, especially in the way how PHP deals with OOP code. Also, FYI, **FACTORY METHOD IS AN ANTIPATTERN.** It is procedural code, that has been masked with object oriented tools. If you want to write good OOP code, there should be no static calls anywhere in it.

Comment: it is hard to push a shared hosting to update its PHP. by the way, eAccelerator is installed, how to make use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you are using some kind of autoloading if the class loading times are so slow. Consider an approach similar to Symfony's APC class loader:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html
https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader

The idea behind it is that it caches the classpaths in APC so the include path for autoloading is not traversed for every request. Anyways I think there is some architechtural issue if the actual php loading is slower than the DB, even more so if its slower than the ORM layer...From my experience loading times are the other way around usually. Which parts of the PHP are slowest in particular. Another approach you can use is also an idea from symfony, where you have a deploy script which upon deployment merges all classes in one file, reducing file system calls, but i dont know if thats going to even be practical in your case, its definitely a speed improvement. Basically every time you have a file system operation its dead slow, so avoid it as much as possible..

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm not using autoloading of class. I create the class when I need it, and set it to null if I finish using it.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor wat?  How can you set class to a null? Are you writing your own garbage collector?